# Powershell Forms - pausing loop with button

Tags: powershell

I have a forms-based script that does a lot of file copies, from various sources. The main loop for copying the files can run for a long time and I'd like to add a pause button to hold processing (until the pause button is pressed again)

Following the advice [here](https://info.sapien.com/index.php/guis/gui-advanced-tips/creating-responsive-loops), I'm using `[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()` to keep the form responsive and provide a way to break out the copy loop gracefully if needed.

I'm struggling to see how I can introduce a button to pause the "ForEach" loop instead of breaking it - can anyone point me in the right direction as my attempts to use Do-Until/While seems to hang the script in some way?

A vastly simplified sample of what I'm doing is below:

```
$StartCopyButton.Add_Click({
    $script:CancelLoop = $false
    $script:PauseToggle = $false
    $CancelButton.Enabled = $true
    $StartCopyButton.Enabled = $false

    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Source -Recurse -File | ForEach {
        Copy-Item -Path $.FullName -Destination $NewDestination
        [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
        If($script:CancelLoop -eq $true) {
            #Exit the loop
            Break;
        }
        If ($script:PauseToggle) {
            Do { 
            [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
            } Until (!$script:PauseToggle)
        }
    }
    $CancelButton.Enabled = $false
    $StartCopyButton.Enabled = $true
})

$CancelButton.Add_Click({
    $script:CancelLoop = $true
})
$PauseButton.Add_Click({
    # Boolean change value to true/false
    $script:PauseToggle = !$script:PauseToggle
})
```

Comment: In your copy loop create a loop, that is active while the stop button is toggled aktive. Inside that loop `DoEvents`. Don't forget that you need to `DoEvents` in the outer loop, too. (haven't tested if this actually works, just an idea)

Comment: Yup thanks, I just realised that I was trying to code this in the wrong place (in the button instead of the loop). I've amended the above and this seems to work, though if there's a more elegant way to code it I'm happy to hear it.

Comment: The more elegant way is to make a separate worker thread. But it's a real pain to control threads in Powershell.

Comment: You should make up your mind if you want a forms application (then use c# or vb.net) **or** a PowerShell script. Mixing these two worlds does not work so well. In a forms application you would use a worker thread. And in PowerShell you would not use pause buttons etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the Pause state and if it's true then do empty loop with DoEvents. Like this (didn't tested it though):

```
$StartCopyButton.Add_Click({
    $script:CancelLoop = $false
    $script:Pause = $false
    $CancelButton.Enabled = $true
    $StartCopyButton.Enabled = $false

    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Source -Recurse -File | ForEach {
        Copy-Item -Path $.FullName -Destination $NewDestination
        [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
        while ($script:Pause -and !$script:CancelLoop) {
            [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
            sleep 0.1
        }
        If($script:CancelLoop -eq $true) {
            #Exit the loop
            Break;
        }
    }
    $CancelButton.Enabled = $false
    $StartCopyButton.Enabled = $true
})

$CancelButton.Add_Click({
    $script:CancelLoop = $true
})
$PauseButton.Add_Click({
    $script:Pause = !$script:Pause
})
```

Comment: @marsze Writing GUI in Powershell is a hack itself :) A lot of pain to make a decent result.

Comment: Yep, I just commented that on the OP

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you need only *one* button for starting & pausing. Here is one very basic approach to illustrate my idea, NOT TESTED:

```
$script:CancelLoop = $false
$script:PauseLoop = $false
$CopyButton.Add_Click({
    # toggle the start/pause state when clicked
    $script:PauseLoop = -not $script:PauseLoop
    if ($script:PauseLoop) {
        $CancelButton.Enabled = $false
        $CopyButton.Text = "Start"
    }
    else {
        $CancelButton.Enabled = $true
        $CopyButton.Text = "Pause"
        # start / resume the loop
        Get-ChildItem $Source -Recurse -File | foreach {
            $newPath = Join-Path $NewDestination $_.Name
            # test if file was already copied
            # (might want to compare modified times too)
            if (-not (Test-Path $newPath)) {
                Copy-Item $_.FullName $newPath
            }
            [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
            if ($script:CancelLoop -or $script:PauseLoop) {
                # exit loop if cancelled or paused
                break
            }
        }
        $CancelButton.Enabled = $false
        $CopyButton.Text = "Start"
    }
})
```

Another approach would be getting all files first, saving them in a collection, and then store the index and pause/resume at that point. But that bears the risk that the list of files might have changed in the meantime. So a really "safe" solution would be more complex.

Comment: Nice idea but it could take some time to resume in case of a big amount of files.

Comment: @montonero As I said, mixing these two worlds won't work well. Just skip the form and punch that command into PowerShell. You can pause the pipeline there whenever you want.

Comment: Compiling a file list isn't really practical - there's millions of files involved and PS resources would become an issue. I editied my original post a while back with the solution I found myself, but like the idea of a single Pause/Stop button.